# Has anyone got a good example of unit of work with multiple repositories that is not using EF?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-of-work

I am about to implement the unit of work pattern with MVC3.

I have:

**MVC Service Layer (BLL)**

**Repository Layer**

**Multiple types of databases**

I want my service layer to get the IUnitOfWork passed to it by my IOC container. (This is easy and not part of this question).

So my service layer will do this: (Note: this is pseudo code)

```
(using unitOfWork)
{
   ProductSqlRepository.Update();
   PersonOracleRepository.Update();
   IUnitOfWork.Commit();
}
```

All the samples I can find use EF. Whilst one of my repositories might use EF others may not.

My question is then, can I use the Unit of work pattern across multiple repositories that may sit above different types of databases (ie... EF, Oracle... other)

So, if I want to wrap an update to a SQL database and an oracle database in the ONE unit of work call, is the unit of work the way to do it.

As I mentioned, all examples I can find are for 100% EF solution, I need to mix and match.

Thanks
RuSs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UnitOfWork scope is essentially already defined in MVC since all of your logic is done within an action. The common pattern I've seen (and what I ended up doing in my app) is to handle your unit of work via an attribute you register globally to your app and handle setting up whatever unit of work logic (transactions etc) you need to in the `OnActionExecuting` and `OnActionExecuted` of that attribute. There are a few caveats like making sure that the action isn't a child action and checking for ModelState errors but there are examples of this online. Also note that if you do not use viewmodels exclusively in your views, you may run into issues with certain frameworks lazy loading data in a view after your unit of work scope has closed.

My project used nHibernate and I used these two posts as inspiration for my implementation. Hopefully they'll give you a few ideas as well.

http://ayende.com/blog/4809/refactoring-toward-frictionless-odorless-code-what-about-transactions

http://slynetblog.blogspot.ca/2011/04/lightweight-nhibernate-and-aspnet-mvc.html